# django 1.6.4 list_filter

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm using Django 1.6.4 with Python 3.3. I would like to have, in my admin page, a Search menu to find a name in my table. My project is 'prova' and the model is 'pazienti'.
I used this code in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from prova.pazienti.models import *

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    data_nascita = models.DateField()


class Admin:
    list_display=('name','surname')
    list_filter=('surname',)
    search_fields=('surname',)
```

But... it doesn't work! 
I tried also do not insert class Admin in models.py but insert this in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from prova.pazienti.models import *

class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('numero_centro','matricola_pz_centro')
    list_filter=('numero_centro',)
    search_fields=('numero_centro',)

admin.site.register(Patient, PatientAdmin)

admin.site.unregister(Patient)
```

But the result is the same: no error but I haven't the search bar!
Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I forget: if I use def __str__ I can see the correct name of columns but with only list_display it doesn't work! So I think that is a problem of Admin class...

Comment: Firstly, there has been no documentation that says to put admin classes inside models for *over six years*, since before version 1.0.  And secondly, your question is confusing, as the names of the fields don't match up, and your comment mentions an issue with `list_display` that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: Don't care name of fields, in the second exemple only I forget to change the real name. I'm studying Django on some books, I'm not an expert (if I were an expert I will not ask this, don't think so?), I tried first what the book says, then something in the django help but it doesn't work. I would like to know if I missed some package or other... thank you

Comment: No, but you are missing explaining what the actual problem is. What does list_display have to do with anything? What is happening, and what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Suppose to happen: have a search bar on the page admin/pazienti/patient where I can search by name and display name and surname in the list of patients;   happen: no errors but the simple page like no code about list_display and list_filter. Tuples are displayed like 'Patient object' and not like 'Name Surname'; if I use -_str_- command I can display 'Name Surname' but obviously I can't insert the search bar

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find...
The code is correct, only in some previous exercise I insert:

```
admin.site.register(Patient)
```

in urls.py, so all things wrote in admin.py were ignored!
Sorry and thank you